# How likely is it for a group of 5 friends to have the same birth month?

Tags: probability

I have the solution, which is $$\frac{1}{12^5}$$ but I do not understand how they got $12^5$. Can someone please explain?

Thanks

Comment: There must have been $6$ friends.  You should probably include that in the question.

Comment: how many friends? it seems you have $6$. and for each the probability is $1/12$ and you multiply it for $5$ times as independent events.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Sorry about that, I forgot to add $5$ which was very important.

Comment: @gekkostate I see but it is still not enough. Because, then you should specify a specific month, then $5$ is okay.

Comment: the question should be like this: what is the probability that a group of $5$ persons share the same birth month, e.g., January.

Comment: If there are $5$ friends, it should be $\frac 1{12^4}$ as the first one can be any month, then the remaining $4$ have to match that one.  It is $\frac 1{12^5}$ if you specify the month in advance.

Comment: @RossMillikan Okay, thanks.

Comment: @gekkostate please modify the question. Neither the question is valid nor a given answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that there were $6$ friends.

Say that the first friend was born in July.  The probability of any of the other friends also being born in July is $\frac{1}{12}$.  Now, assuming that the birth months of the friends are independent (a reasonable assumption), then the joint probability is just the product of the individual probabilities.

$$
\begin{align}
    P(&F_2=\text{July} \textbf{ and } F_3=\text{July} \textbf{ and } \cdots \textbf{ and } F_6=\text{July}\;) \\
    &= P(F_2=\text{July}) \cdot P(F_3=\text{July}) \cdots P(F_6=\text{July}) \\
    &= \frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{12} \cdots \frac{1}{12} \\
    &= \left( \frac{1}{12} \right)^5 \\
    &= \frac{1}{12^5}
\end{align}
$$

There is nothing special about July, of course.  The argument is strictly analogous for any other month that the first friend was born in.

Comment: The question, states that there were $5$ friends.

Comment: You can see how to modify my answer in that case, then.  As in Ross Millikan's comment, if you specify that all $5$ friends have a *particular* birth month, then you obtain the answer $\frac{1}{12^5}$.